# How to undefine an attribute in Grakn?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am working with Grakn and I want to undefine an attribute.

To do this, do I first have to undefine it from an entity?

For example, if I have the below:

```
person sub entity, has name; 
name sub attribute, datatype string;
```

Can I do this:

```
undefine 
name sub attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Graql, you can indeed undefine an attribute as you indicated:

```
undefine
name sub attribute;
```

don't forget to `commit` after!

https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/schema/concepts

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Another question, can I undefine if there are instances of attributes? Or do I need to delete all attribute instances before undefining?

Comment: you will need to remove the instances before undefining the attribute